# Java 6 Upload file - Check MimeType with annotation

Tags: java, file-upload, mime-types, java-ee-6

I have multipart form which contains upload file filed. The request to server looks like:

```
POST http://localhost:9080/rest/document/createAttachmentByFormData?docId=421 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2806029
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://localhost:9080
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryYtXkHtK8fLnpK8AO
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

Some Text
------WebKitFormBoundaryYtXkHtK8fLnpK8AO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="textfield-1226-inputEl"

ATTACHMENT
------WebKitFormBoundaryYtXkHtK8fLnpK8AO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="thefile"; filename="somefile.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Then I have method which handles uploading file:

```
@POST
@Path("/createAttachmentByFormData")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response createDocAndAttachment(@FormParam("thefile") File theFile, @QueryParam("docId") int docId) {

}
```

Is there any way to use annotation to check MimeType of the uploaded file in the form. So in this example request, the form field `thefile` contains file and which is type of `application/pdf`

So I need a way to use annotation to say to method to reject any request where `Content-Type` of form field `thefile` is different then `application/pdf`